# Fitting Linear Regression with one row of data - Scikit Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've my data in the following format

http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_xK7cevIoVs_0.py

Basically what I've is I've one row per data and I want to find linear combination between the variables to predict the output variable.

PNL is my output variable, GRID_MTH_DT is different per row and I need that.
All others are my independent variables.

What I want is an equation like this

PNL = linear_fn(WTI,Brent,Canada C5,Canadian Heavy,Gulf Coast ASCI,Gulf Coast LLS,Gulf Coast Mars,Gulf Coast St. James,Midwest Bakken,Midwest WTS,Midwest Midland,Midwest WTI)

How can I achieve this?

I have tried to run and fit this into a linear regression model using scikit learn, but all the coefficients come out as 0

('Coefficients: \n', array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), '\n')

I'd appreciate any help here.

Comment: How many rows of data do you have? Your title suggests that you only have a single row of data. If that's true, then you've got a severely underdetermined linear system: there are multiple possible solutions, including one with all coefficients except the constant coefficient equal to zero.

Comment: @MarkDickinson - I've several rows of data, but I need to fit each row of data and get its own equation.

Could you please share some possible solutions on this one.

Comment: I think you are going to have to include some code, to show how you are preprocessing the data. Also you need to clearly explain what you mean with 'one row of data'. I think you just want traditional linear regression.

Comment: @nEO: What you're describing sounds a bit nonsensical from a mathematical point of view. Given several inputs and a single output, there are *many* possible choices of linear function that return that output from those inputs. One of those possible choices is the linear function where all coefficients of the input variables are zero, and the constant coefficient matches your desired output. I suspect that's what scikit learn is finding. If you give more information about what you're doing, we might be able to suggest better approaches.